# How can I render different div on the basis of a list object that is passed to the partial view from the main view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I am actually stuck in a situation where I am not able to render multiple div's on the basis of a list of object. Below is the code that I have written:

**Main View**

```
<div class="section-wrap break " id="ServicePlan_PrioritySection" data-bind="foreach:applicationview.viewmodel.ListMembers()">
        @{Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Home/ServicePlan/_Priority1.cshtml");}
    </div>
```

**Partial View**

```
<div class="priority-timeline">
<div class="timeline-list">
    <div class="timeline-list-items" style="margin-left: 75px">
        <h6 data-bind="text:hasValue(Title())?Title():'&nbsp;'"></h6>
        <div class="timeline-bar" id="resizable" data-bind="foreach:applicationview.viewmodel.ListMembers()[0].UpcomingActivities()">
            <div class="priority-icon">
                @*<img src="service-plan/image/img_1.png" alt="">*@
                <div class="detail-popup">
                    <strong data-bind="text:hasValue(Title())?Title():'&nbsp;'"></strong>
                    <p data-bind="text:hasValue(Description())?Description():'&nbsp;'">
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>           
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now under the main view, the list object **applicationView.ViewModel.ListOfMembers()** contains 3 values and because of this the partial view is rendered three times which is working fine. However, each three values contains multiple values inside it. i.e. the object **applicationview.viewmodel.ListMembers()[0].UpcomingActivities() contains 3 values** and so on. Now on the basis of these three values of MainMembers(), i would like to render three div's under the partial view and want to use the current values of the selected UpcomingActivities. If I am using the partial view code as listed above, I am getting the same value for all the divs rendered as I am using the value under foreach like **foreach:cebMapsApp.cebMapsViewModel.viewModel.CebSupportedPriorities()[0].UpcomingActivities()** i.e the 0th value.

How can I use the current selected values of UpcomingActivities of cebPriorities so that I can render the divs properly under the partial view and simultaneously use the current value as well inside the div.

Thanks,

Comment: `foreach:applicationview.viewmodel.ListMembers()[0].UpcomingActivities()` wil always render same value in all divs. Change to `foreach:UpcomingActivities()`

Comment: I did this, but its not working

Comment: check the html part in fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/27259/ . dandy rightly pointedout , check console for any errors .